# Android sharing selected text to other apps

Tags: java, android, beginner

I am somewhat new to Java.  I want to know if this is the proper way to share text with other Android applications, and if I am properly determining if the text is selected.  Is there a better way to share the selected text?  Is my decision statement proper?  The app works just fine.

```
package com.kylelk.sharedemo;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private Button shareBtn;
    private EditText textToShare;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        shareBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareText);   
        shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                //Get the selected text
                EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textToShare);
                int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart(); 
                int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();
                String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);

                //if no text is selected share the entire text area.
                if(selectedText.length() == 0){
                    textToShare = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textToShare);
                    String dataToShare = textToShare.getText().toString();
                    selectedText = dataToShare;
                }

                //Share the text
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(); 
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, selectedText); 
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
                startActivity(sendIntent);

            }           
        });             
    }
}
```

Here is the complete project: https://github.com/kylelk/ShareDemo

Comment: While Code Review does focus on reviewing working code, I think this specific question would be better answered by Android programmers, it's more about correctly using the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly I believe you have answered this question yourself: **The app works just fine.**

From what I can see, you are using the intent [exactly as you are supposed to](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). You are also using `EditText` properly. But, because you have come all the way here I guess you want to hear some suggestions/criticism as well so I have tried really hard to come up with something:

- You're inconsistent in adding spaces to your code. The best practice is to use `VariableType variable = something;` but in three lines you are writing `VariableType variable=something;` which makes the code a little bit harder to read.
- I don't think you need to temporarily store the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` variables. (If you think it looks cleaner to store them in temporary variables, then by all means continue to do so) This code would be enough:

  ```
  String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(et.getSelectionStart(), et.getSelectionEnd());
  ```

  Or if you think that line is too long,

  ```
  String text = et.getText().toString();
  String selectedText = text.substring(et.getSelectionStart(), et.getSelectionEnd());
  ```
- Consider what would happen if there is nothing at all stored in the `EditText`, do you still want to start an intent even if the string is empty?